# SQL to Linq group by count

Tags: sql, linq, count, group-by

I have a single column in a table to count specific rows. The sql query is as below:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN trail LIKE 'ClassA%'   THEN 'ClassA'
    WHEN trail LIKE 'ClassB%' THEN 'ClassB'
    WHEN trail LIKE 'SemA%' THEN 'SemesterA'
    WHEN trail LIKE 'SemB%' THEN 'SemesterB'
  END AS Logs
, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM Logs where s_date >= 'from date from UI' and e_date <= 'to date from ui'
GROUP BY 
  CASE
    WHEN trail LIKE 'ClassA%'   THEN 'ClassA'
    WHEN trail LIKE 'ClassB%' THEN 'ClassB'
    WHEN trail LIKE 'SemA%' THEN 'SemesterA'
    WHEN trail LIKE 'SemB%' THEN 'SemesterB'
END
```

The above query result in sql fine as

```
ClassA 20
ClassB 5
SemesterA 2
SemesterB 50
```

Now, I need to change this sql to Linq with a date filter (from date, to date).
Please suggest change in query to simplyfy it.
Thanks

Tried:-

```
var data = _db.Logs.Where(p => p.trail.StartsWith("ClassA") && (p.SDate.Date >= CDate.Date && p.SDate.Date <= FDate.Date)).GroupBy(p => p.trail.StartsWith("ClassA")).Select(s =>
            new
            {
                source = "Class - A total",
                percentage = s.Count()

            }).Union(_db.Logs.Where(p => p.trail.StartsWith("ClassB") && (p.SDate.Date >= CDate.Date && p.SDate.Date <= FDate.Date)).GroupBy(p => p.trail.StartsWith("ClassB")).Select(s =>
            new
            {
                source = "Class - B total",
                percentage = s.Count()

            }).Union(_db.Logs.Where(p => p.trail.StartsWith("SemesterA") && (p.SDate.Date >= CDate.Date && p.SDate.Date <= FDate.Date)).GroupBy(p => p.trail.StartsWith("SemesterA")).Select(s =>
            new
            {
                source = "Semester - A total",
                percentage = s.Count()

            }).Union(_db.Logs.Where(p => p.trail.StartsWith("SemesterB") && (p.SDate.Date >= CDate.Date && p.SDate.Date <= FDate.Date)).GroupBy(p => p.trail.StartsWith("SemesterB")).Select(s =>
            new
            {
                source = "Semester - B total",
                percentage = s.Count()

            })))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing all the interesting starting keys in an enumerable of some sort and then using the built in group by method overload which outputs a result mapped from the key,group pairs (c.f. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549393(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
string[] startingKeys = new string[] {"ClassA","ClassB","SemsterA","SemesterB"};

var data =_db.Logs.Where(p=>(p.SDate.Date >= CDate.Date && p.SDate.Date <= FDate.Date)&&startingKeys.Any(k=>p.Logs.StartsWith(k))).GroupBy(p=>startingKeys.Where(k=>p.Logs.StartsWith(k)).First(),(key,items)=>new {source=key,count = items.Count()})
```

One advantage of this method is you can change the starting keys at runtime if you feel like it.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the query and url. I missed 1 part in linq query...The source is text only and not compared to database. ex - source = "Class - A total". I have updated the query in post. –